# Can MATLAB create a Future for executing a function without ever invoking a function on a worker?

Tags: matlab, asynchronous, background-processing

MATLAB's `parallel.Future` class provides useful functionality for making responsive code that avoids blocking user input and is able to `cancel` previously requested tasks when new input means they are no longer required.

However the only top-level function I know of which returns a `Future` object is `parfeval` which either runs functions on a parallel pool or on a background worker. This is not suitable for all functions, for example plotting, which require interaction with the main MATLAB process and yields an error if used in the context of a `parfeval` call.

However it isn't outright impossible to invoke such functionality asynchronously, because the `afterAll` and `afterEach` methods that `Future`s have execute functions on the main MATLAB process, and are themselves represented by `Future` objects.

Thus if we call a completely trivial function on the background pool we can invoke some plotting function immediately afterwards and gain access to control over its execution. For example, the following:

```
function doTask(ind)
    disp("Starting task #" + ind)
    for ii = 1:100
        plot(rand(5,1))
        drawnow
    end
    disp("Completed task #" + ind)
end

function responsiveCallback(~,evt)
    cbo = evt.Source;
    n = numel(cbo.UserData);
    if n > 0
        disp("Cancelling " + n + " Future(s)")
        cbo.UserData.cancel;
    end
    
    cbo.UserData = [cbo.UserData;
        parfeval(backgroundPool,@eye,0) ...
            .afterAll(@() doTask(n + 1),0)];
end
uibutton(ButtonPushedFcn = @responsiveCallback);
```

sets up a button. Clicked just once, it produces the output:

```
Starting task #1
Completed task #1
```

Clicked twice in short succession, the output is:

```
Starting task #1
Cancelling 1 Future(s)
Starting task #2
Completed task #2
```

Execution of the function that output `Starting task #1` is aborted before it has completed, even though it was executing on the main MATLAB thread.

Being forced to do something like `parfeval(backgroundPool,@eye,0)` just to call `afterAll` is an ugly formulation though; it makes code harder to follow, feels like a hack, and the traffic to/from the background pool might even impact performance in some contexts. Is there a way to produce the same behaviour directly without the `parfeval` stage?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. In your example code, the `afterAll` future `x` is cancelled before it ever starts running. If it did start running, then you wouldn't be able to cancel it until it had completed, because cancellation requires the MATLAB thread. So I can't see how this approach is ever going to be particularly useful.

Comment: You can use the timer object for “asynchronous” execution. Putting that in quotes because the main thread, by definition, does just one thing at the time.

Comment: @Edric my example was overly simplistic but I've updated it to demonstrate that functions called by `afterAll` can still be terminated early by cancellation if you get control of the MATLAB main thread while it is in progress, e.g. with UI interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [R2021b and later](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.pool.parfeval.html#mw_edb10125-8320-4dcd-a772-05ece8c8021e), you can pass an empty `parallel.Pool` instance as the first argument to `parfeval` to explicitly request execution in the calling process. I.e. use

```
fut = parfeval(parallel.Pool.empty, @fcn, nOut, args)
```

This might work for you, but you still have the awkwardness of the co-operative scheduling to deal with (there's only 1 main MATLAB thread, and you need to use `drawnow` or similar to yield).

Comment: That's a much more appealing pattern! It should be noted that this doesn't produce exactly the same behaviour as in my MCVE because the output of `disp` is captured in the `parallel.FevalFuture.Diary` property. Clearly there are differences in the execution environment. But these will often be unimportant differences.